# rewriting rules, excluding condition

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Have a following rewriting rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(js|css|images)/

RewriteRule section/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /index.php?controller=section&method=index&param=$1
RewriteRule category/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /index.php?controller=category&method=products&param=$1
RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&param=$3
RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2
```

Now, when I call for /js/jquery.js, I get the file fine. But if the file is one folder level deeper, eg. /js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js, it doesn't. It has something to do with section and category rules as everything works fine when I remove those two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the condition for each rule, the condition only applies to the immediately following rule. The reason why it works when you remove the 2 section and category rules is because the condition is being applied to the 3rd rule (which is what's messing you up). You need the condition repeated for each rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(js|css|images)/
RewriteRule section/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /index.php?controller=section&method=index&param=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(js|css|images)/
RewriteRule category/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /index.php?controller=category&method=products&param=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(js|css|images)/
RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&param=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(js|css|images)/
RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2
```